# Check for Validation Errors on Submit Button Click

Tags: infopath, validation

I have an infopath 2010 form that already has some VB code behind it.

I want to create a SubmitButton clicked event that checks for validation errors before it submits.. I have an example in C# and i am wondering what the equivalent is in VB

Thanks

c# :-

```
public void SubmitButton_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlForm form = sender as XmlForm;
        if (form.Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                SubmitForm();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.ViewInfos.SwitchView("FormError");
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ViewInfos.SwitchView("ValidationError");
        }
    }
```

VB ????

```
Public Sub SubmitButton_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ClickedEventArgs)
        ' Write your code here.
End Sub
```

Comment: StackOverflow would probably be a better place for this question.  This site is dedicated to questions based directly on the Microsoft SharePoint platform (notice you are collecting close votes here). You can review this here for more clarification http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use developerfusion.com code conversion utility:
[C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

```
Public Sub SubmitButton_Clicked(sender As Object, e As ClickedEventArgs)
   Dim form As XmlForm = TryCast(sender, XmlForm)
   If form.Errors.Count = 0 Then
       Try
           SubmitForm()
       Catch ex As Exception
           Me.ViewInfos.SwitchView("FormError")
           ex.Message.ToString()
       End Try
   Else
       Me.ViewInfos.SwitchView("ValidationError")
   End If
End Sub
```